# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 11 (char 11) in TD Ameritrade API

Tags: python, json, api

I am pretty new to api and python know a little bit of code, but I am trying to pull stock data from Td Ameritrade Api. 
I have followed a couple of youtube videos to get this code and some how it works for them, but when I run it I get an error: full error is below. If anyone knows how to get around this it would be much appreciated.

```
endpoint = r"https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/{}/pricehistory".format('GOOG')

payload = {'apikey': apikey,
           'periodType': 'day',
           'frequencyType' : 'minute',
           'frequency' : '1',
           'period' : '2',
           'needExtendedHourData' : 'true'}

content = requests.get(url = endpoint, params = payload)
print()

data = content.json()

print(data)
```

---

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-6604869a0d57> in <module>
     10 content = requests.get(url = endpoint, params = payload)
     11 
---> 12 data = content.json()
     13 
     14 print(data)

c:\users\steve\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    888                 try:
    889                     return complexjson.loads(
--> 890                         self.content.decode(encoding), **kwargs
    891                     )
    892                 except UnicodeDecodeError:

c:\users\steve\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

c:\users\steve\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

c:\users\steve\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 11 (char 11)
```

Comment: Add a `print(repr(content.text))` so that you can see what you're getting back.

Comment: it returns "error":"Invalid ApiKey" but I also tried print(content.staus_code) and it returns 500 which i read, means the servers are not working I believe. So I am completely confused on what would be the problem with this, but thank you for your help. @JustinEzequiel

Comment: So contact the server admins and verify that your API key is correct.

Comment: 1. Make sure you got the right API Code, follow these instructions: [TD Ameritrade Authentication](https://developer.tdameritrade.com/content/authentication-faq) 
2. Make sure you call the API with https, not http and
3. The thing that helped me the most was using their online API site to make calls, since I then knew for sure the format was correct. So make a basic call to get your account from their website, and you can probably puzzle out why yours is failing.